# SQL - SUMIF substitute?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

This question is best asked using an example - if I have daily data (in this case, daily Domestic Box Office for the movie Elvis), how can I sum only the weekend values?

If the data looks like this:

| Date | DBO |
| --- | --- |
| 6/24/2022 | 12755467 |
| 6/25/2022 | 9929779 |
| 6/26/2022 | 8526333 |
| 6/27/2022 | 4253038 |
| 6/28/2022 | 5267391 |
| 6/29/2022 | 4010762 |
| 6/30/2022 | 3577241 |
| 7/1/2022 | 5320812 |
| 7/2/2022 | 6841224 |
| 7/3/2022 | 6290576 |
| 7/4/2022 | 4248679 |
| 7/5/2022 | 3639110 |
| 7/6/2022 | 3002182 |
| 7/7/2022 | 2460108 |
| 7/8/2022 | 3326066 |
| 7/9/2022 | 4324040 |
| 7/10/2022 | 3530965 |

I'd like to be able to get results that look like this:

| Weekend | DBO Sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 31211579 |
| 2 | 18452612 |
| 3 | 11181071 |

Also - not sure how tricky this would be but would love to include percent change v. last weekend.

| Weekend | DBO Sum | % Change |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 31211579 |  |
| 2 | 18452612 | -41% |
| 3 | 11181071 | -39% |

I tried this with CASE WHEN but I got the results in different columns, which was not what I was looking for.

```
SELECT 
  ,SUM(CASE 
    WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2022-06-24' AND '2022-06-26' THEN index 
    ELSE 0
    END) AS Weekend1
 ,SUM(CASE 
    WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-03' THEN index 
    ELSE 0
    END) AS Weekend2
  ,SUM(CASE 
    WHEN DATE BETWEEN '2022-07-08' AND '2022-07-10' THEN index 
    ELSE 0
    END) AS Weekend3
FROM Elvis
```

Comment: Why not use `dayofweek` as documented here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions ? Maybe something like `SUM(CASE WHEN dayofweek(date) IN (1, 7) THEN dbo ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 0):

I would start by filtering the data on week-end days only. Then we can group by week to get the index sum ; the last step is to use window functions to compare each week-end with the previous one:

```
select iso_week,
    row_number() over(order by iso_week) weekend_number,
    sum(index) as dbo_sum,
    ( sum(index) - lag(sum(index) over(order by iso_week) )
        / nullif(lag(sum(index)) over(order by iso_week), 0) as ratio_change
from (
    select e.*, extract(isoweek from date) iso_week
    from elvis e
    where extract(dayofweek from date) in (1, 7)
) e
group by iso_week
order by iso_week
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select *, 
  round(100 * safe_divide(dbo_sum - lag(dbo_sum) over(order by week), lag(dbo_sum) over(order by week)), 2) change_percent
from (
  select extract(week from date + 2) week, sum(dbo) dbo_sum
  from your_table
  where extract(dayofweek from date + 2) in (1, 2, 3)
  group by week
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]